# What is a word that would describe somebody who does not realize or accept their own self-worth

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I am looking for a word to describe someone who is always downbeat about themself and will not accept a compliment. This person also believes they are ugly or fat or untalented, when they clearly are not.

Comment: low self-esteem?

Comment: *self-deprecating*, *self-abasing*

Comment: _Having a poor self-image_?

Comment: No one here has answered the question. Everyone responded with an adjective when the poster was looking for a noun. Sadly, I have not an answer as I came here seeking the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

How about *self-hatred* or *self-loathing*?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hatred):

> **Self-hatred** (also called **self-loathing**) refers to an extreme dislike or hatred of oneself, or being angry at or even prejudiced
>   against oneself. [emphasis added]
>
> The term "self-hatred" is used infrequently by psychologists and
>   psychiatrists, who would usually describe people who hate themselves
>   as "persons with low self-esteem".

Google search:

> [*self-hatred*](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=self-hate&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8):
>   intense dislike of oneself.

The Wikipedia excerpt also suggests a person with *low self-esteem*, already mentioned by @JohnFeltz. From M-W:

> [*self-esteem*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/self-esteem):
>   a reasonable or justifiable sense of one's worth or importance

A person with *low self-esteem* lacks a sense of their own worth, value, or importance.

If you're looking for a word that's less extreme, how about *insecure*? Also from M-W:

> [*insecure*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insecure): not
>   confident or sure

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely referring to someone who is ***self-doubting***.

ODO:

> **[self-doubting](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/self-doubting)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **Lacking confidence in oneself and one's abilities**; unconfident.
>   ‘a fragile, confused, self-doubting paranoiac’
>
> ‘He once turned down the chance of becoming a candidate for
>   parliament: he was much too self-effacing, and self-doubting, to do
>   that.’
>
> ‘Most of the students were uncertain and self-doubting about their
>   capacity to write a paper, speak publicly, or rebel against
>   authority.’
>
> ‘These were geniuses too busy and self-doubting to think of themselves
>   as geniuses.’

Answer (score 0):

The person "belittles" himself. Though ***belittle*** is a verb, it captures the idea of having a low self esteem.

You can call the person [***unconfident***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unconfident) in a milder way. An unconfident person is not confident or is hesitant.

You can also say that the person constantly ***undervalues*** or ***underestimates*** himself. He doesn't realize his own worth or chooses to dismiss it as insignificant.

As suggested by Drew, ***self abasing*** is another option.